# "Spatie\\Async\\Output\\ParallelError::fromException('Xdebug: async await never resolves, keeps waiting

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

I am using https://github.com/spatie/async inside a laravel app for an operation that takes 1-2 seconds per user without async functionality.

I made sure to install the right extensions as documented on the package in my docker file

```
docker-php-ext-install zip bz2 pdo_mysql pcntl posix soap
```

I am getting this error

```
"Spatie\\Async\\Output\\ParallelError::fromException('Xdebug:
```

When I add async functionality it gets stuck waiting and never resolves. Here is the code I am using.

```
    private function getUsersFromSurveyCycleExperienceStatus(array $args, Collection $users): array
    {
        $users_ids_collected = [];
        $pool = Pool::create();
        $pool->concurrency(4);
        $pool->timeout(10);

        $users_include = [];

        foreach ($users as $single_user) {
            $pool[] = async(function () use (&$single_user, &$args, &$users_ids_collected) {
                $scer = $single_user->survey_cycle_experience_reviews_reviewer($args['survey_cycle_id'])->get();
                if (!empty($scer)) {
                    $users_ids_collected[] = $this->filterUsersByExperienceReviewsStatus($scer, $args['survey_cycle_experience_status']);
                }
            });
        }
        await($pool);
        $users_include = [];
        foreach ($users_ids_collected as $user_ids) {
            if (count($user_ids) > 0) {
                $users_include = array_merge($users_include, $user_ids);
            }
        }
        return $users_include;
    }
```

I have tried different concurrency levels (i.e. 20, and 4).
I have tried changing the array size for $users and it had no effect (i.e. from 600+ users to 1).

Looking for ideas to why this would not be resolving, thanks!